# i am getting mulltilin statement error in python can anyone suggest me

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector

cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='Noot@123',
                            host='127.0.0.1',
                            database='grocery_store')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
query=("SELECT products.product_id, products.name, products.uom_id, products.price_per_unit, uom.uom_name"
'FROM products inner join uom on products.uom_id=uom.uom_id')

cursor.execute(query)

for(product_id,name,uom_id,price_per_unit,uom_name) in cursor:
    print(product_id,name,uom_id,price_per_unit,uom_name)

cnx.close()
```

**ERROR i am getting:** mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join uom on products.uom_id=uom.uom_id' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a space before FROM

```
import mysql.connector

cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='dc2019DB',
                            host='127.0.0.1',
                            database='testdb')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
query=("SELECT products.product_id, products.name, products.uom_id, products.price_per_unit, uom.uom_name"
 ' FROM products inner join uom on products.uom_id=uom.uom_id')

cursor.execute(query)

for(product_id,name,uom_id,price_per_unit,uom_name) in cursor:
    print(product_id,name,uom_id,price_per_unit,uom_name)

cnx.close()
```

Comment: Python will automatically concatenate adjacent strings, so the "+" operator is redundant.  But you are right that a space must be inserted before "FROM".